# How do I update my url pattern to django 1.10?

Tags: python, django, url-pattern

So I'm going through PluralSight's 'Django Fundamentals' and it's based on an older version of Django. As I'm writing this now I am using Django 1.10 which I believe is the up to date version. As I'm following the video I'm creating a database for a fictional school. This is my url pattern based on the one on the Pluralsight tutorial:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from school.views import home

    urlpatterns += patterns(
        'django.contrib.auth.views',

        url(r'^login/$', 'login',
           {'template_name': 'login.html'},
           name = 'school_login'),

        url(r'^logout/$', 'logout',
           {'next_page': 'school_home'},
           name = 'school_logout'),
        )
```

---

UPDATE:

I have now changed it according to the suggestion from @karthir, and have included ALL of the urls:

```
  from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from school.views import home

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #url(r'^$', home, name = 'home') #school.views.home')

    #url(r'^$', 'main.views.home', name = 'school_home')
    url(r'^$', home, name = 'home')
]

urlpatterns = [
    #'django.contrib.auth.views',


    url(r'^login/$', 'login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name = 'school_login'),

    url(r'^logout/$', 'logout', {'next_page': 'school_home'},  name = 'school_logout'),
]
```

This is the new error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper
 at 0x03CD92B8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in
wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 374,
 in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 361,
 in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81,
in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in c
heck_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in c
heck_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in _
_get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 313, in ur
l_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in _
_get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 306, in ur
lconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\schoolDatabase\schoolDatabase\urls.py", line 23, in
<module>
    url(r'^$', 'main.views.home', name = 'school_home')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 85, in
 url
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of incl
ude().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

Now how to I update it so that it works with Django 1.10? I think this has to do with the fact that I don't know how to update settings.py to add the TEMPLATE_DIRS.

This is my settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for schoolDatabase project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '!^ht#05ke0msws0%qt2ctve@cwn*-!=-&!+o^bkhc!16^&m^!q'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'school'
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'schoolDatabase.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'schoolDatabase.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),

        #'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        #'NAME': 'wadzanai_school',
        #'USER': 'wadzanai_school',
        #'PASSWORD': 'OberynViper01',
        #'HOST': '10.169.0.121',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        #'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
```

Comment: any errors you can add to the question?

Comment: You have more than just the few URLs you showed. Check the file from the error log.

Comment: I've added ALL the URLS